# Ibanez Rg series lead guitar

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, rhythm

I own a Ibanez RG lead and was wondering if I can play rhythm with it. Just not sure and don't want to damage it with the strumming.

Comment: Guitars don't come in rhythm & lead variants.. nor really since the 70's do guitarists ;)

Comment: Don't be afraid to play your guitars with any way you like, people! It's just gonna be fine

Comment: The strings will break before anything on the guitar breaks

Comment: You'll probably get a more even pattern of fret wear if you play some rhythm and some lead...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot damage it with strumming (well, over time you can start to wear down the paintwork. A lot of time)

Guitars are not designed to be rhythm or lead, they are just stringed instruments which can be played with [fingertips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v35YhhzCrYk), [nails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdKtACC4EvU), or a pick (or a [bow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7R6yUyUPd7o), an [electric drill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVonlzhy7Lk), etc)

I have a nice 7-string RG, and while I play lead, some of our songs require seriously hard chugging attack.

Your guitar will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think that you'd damage it would be if you thought you needed heavier strings in order to play rhythm (you don't!). The wrong gauge of strings can bend the neck forwards, which would make the guitar harder to play - but even then, a good guitar technician can get it straight again, or changing back to the recommended string gauge would let it relax back to where it wants to be.